# Hide button in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, button, touchableopacity

I want to hide Sign Up and I use the `disable` attribute of `TouchableOpacity` but it does not seem to work

```
 const isInvalid = 
       passwordOne !== passwordTwo || 
       passwordOne === "" || 
       email === "" || 
       username === "";

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} disabled={isInvalid}>
   <Text style={styles.buttonText} onPress={this.handleSignUp}>
      Sign up
   </Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

But the Sign Up button is not hidden

[image]

My code:

```
import ....

const INITIAL_STATE = {
...
};

export default class Signup extends Component<{}> {

  handleSignUp = () => {
    ...
  };

  render() {

    const isInvalid =
      passwordOne !== passwordTwo ||
      passwordOne === "" ||
      email === "" ||
      username === "";
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <TextInput .../>
        <TextInput .../>
        <TextInput ... />
        <TextInput ... />

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} disabled={isInvalid}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText} onPress={this.handleSignUp}>
            Sign up
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>


      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use display "none" like this:

```
const isInvalid = 
   passwordOne !== passwordTwo || 
   passwordOne === "" || 
   email === "" || 
   username === "";

const display = isInvalid ? "none" : "flex";

<TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, {display}]}> // Put display value here
  <Text style={styles.buttonText} onPress={this.handleSignUp}>
    Sign up
  </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you are doing this,

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} disabled={isInvalid}>
   <Text style={styles.buttonText} onPress={this.handleSignUp}>
      Sign up
   </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Do this:

```
{isInvalid && (<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} disabled={isInvalid}>
   <Text style={styles.buttonText} onPress={this.handleSignUp}>
      Sign up
   </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>)}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
One way is to move the desired code to a different function and call it through your render and take decision in your function whether you want to render it or not.

The advantage here is that you will get some performance boost since your are not rendering something that is not needed. Instead of hiding it through styles.

i.e:

renderSignupButton(isValid){
 if(isValid){
  return(
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} >
      <Text style={styles.buttonText} onPress={this.handleSignUp}>
       Sign up
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
 }

 return null;
}

render(){

const isInvalid =
      passwordOne !== passwordTwo ||
      passwordOne === "" ||
      email === "" ||
      username === "";

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput .../>
        <TextInput .../>
        <TextInput ... />
        <TextInput ... />

        {this.renderSignupButton(isInvalid)}

      </View>
    );

}

    enter code here
```